# How to resolve a Magento compilation error?

Tags: php, magento

I've tried to enable the Compilation mode. But after enabling it I'm getting following error.

[image]

I tried disable the following code in config.php.

```
define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

But no result.

Comment: what is **`FILE`**? I supposed it should be **`__FILE__`**

Comment: It's __FILE__ but in editor view it's showing FILE.

Comment: Check this out http://iamvikram.com/magento-compiler-mode-compilation-process/

Comment: @mani Do you want to disable the compilation?